# How do I put the gcd in the constructor?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to put the gcd into the constructor. I got the gcd to work outside of the class but I cant get it to work when I try to put in the constructor. I could use some help.

This is the code that I have that works:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom
    def __str__(self):
        if self.num == 0:
            return str(0)
        elif self.num > self.den:
            if self.den == 1:
                return str(self.num)
            else:
                return str(self.num // self.den)+\
                   ' '+str(self.num%self.den)+\
                   '/'+str(self.den)
        else:
            return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
    def show(self):
        print(self.num,"/",self.den)
    def __add__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                     self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
    def __sub__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den - \
                     self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
    def __mul__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.num 
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
    def __truediv__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den 
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.num
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
    def __gt__(self,other):
        frac1 = self.num*other.den 
        frac2 = self.den * other.num
        if frac1 > frac2:
            return self.num//self.den
        else:
            return other.num//other.den

    def __eq__(self, other):
        firstnum = self.num * other.den
        secondnum = other.num * self.den

        return firstnum == secondnum
def gcd(m,n):
    while m%n != 0:
        oldm = m
        oldn = n
        m = oldn
        n = oldm%oldn
    return n
def main():
    try:
        getNum1 = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))
        getDen1 = int(input("Enter a denominator: "))
        getNum2 = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))
        getDen2 = int(input("Enter a denominator: "))
        f1 = Fraction(getNum1,getDen2)
        f2 = Fraction(getNum2,getDen2)

        print("[",f1,"]","[",f2,"]",sep='')

        f3 = f1 + f2
        print("Adding Fractions:",f3)
        f3 = f1 - f2
        print("Subtracting Fraction:",f3)
        f3 = f1 * f2
        print("Multiply Fraction:",f3)
        f3 = f1 / f2
        print("Dividing Fraction:",f3)
        if f1 > f2:
            print(f1,"Greater than",f2)
        else:
            print(f2,"Greater than",f1)

        if f1 == f2:
            print("Fractions are equal")
        else:
            print("Fractions are not equal")
    except:
        input("new Fraction")
main()
```

This is where I am trying to put it in the constructor:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom
        self.gcd = n
        while self.den%other.den != 0:
            oldm = self.den
            oldn = other.den

            m = oldn
            n = oldm%oldn
        return n

    def __str__(self):
        if self.num == 0:
            return str(0)
        elif self.num > self.den:
            if self.den == 1:
                return str(self.num)
            else:
                return str(self.num // self.den)+\
                   ' '+str(self.num%self.den)+\
                   '/'+str(self.den)
        else:
            return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)

    def show(self):
        print(self.num,"/",self.den)

    def __add__(self,otherfraction,gcd):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                     self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = self.gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __sub__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den - \
                     self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = self.gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __mul__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.num 
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = self.gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __truediv__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den 
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.num
        common = self.gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __gt__(self,other):
        frac1 = self.num*other.den 
        frac2 = self.den * other.num
        if frac1 > frac2:
            return self.num//self.den
        else:
            return other.num//other.den

    def __eq__(self, other):
        firstnum = self.num * other.den
        secondnum = other.num * self.den

        return firstnum == secondnum




def main():
    #try:
        getNum1 = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))
        getDen1 = int(input("Enter a denominator: "))

        getNum2 = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))
        getDen2 = int(input("Enter a denominator: "))

        f1 = Fraction(getNum1,getDen2)
        f2 = Fraction(getNum2,getDen2)

        print("[",f1,"]","[",f2,"]",sep='')


        f3 = f1 + f2
        print("Adding Fractions:",f3)
        f3 = f1 - f2
        print("Subtracting Fraction:",f3)

        f3 = f1 * f2
        print("Multiply Fraction:",f3)

        f3 = f1 / f2
        print("Dividing Fraction:",f3)

        if f1 > f2:
            print(f1,"Greater than",f2)
        else:
            print(f2,"Greater than",f1)

        if f1 == f2:
            print("Fractions are equal")
        else:
            print("Fractions are not equal")

    #except:
        #input("new Fraction")


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def gcd(m,n):
    while m%n != 0:
        oldm = m
        oldn = n
        m = oldn
        n = oldm%oldn
    return n
```

This is your `gcd` function, taking two parameters `m` and `n` and returning the gcd as `n`.

So in order to inline this function within your constructor, you just need to provide `n` and `m` correctly, and then save the final gcd result:

```
def __init__(self,top,bottom):
    self.num = top
    self.den = bottom

    # gcd arguments
    m, n = self.num, self.den

    # original gcd code, using `n` and `m`
    while m%n != 0:
        oldm = m
        oldn = n
        m = oldn
        n = oldm%oldn

    # instead of returning the gcd `n`, save it in the instance:
    self.gcd = n
```

Note though that you also can keep the function as a function and just call it in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self,top,bottom):
    self.num = top
    self.den = bottom
    self.gcd = gcd(self.num, self.den)
```

This would be generally a cleaner solution as it keeps the (unrelated) gcd logic out of your type and just utilizes it.

---

Since you want to make the `gcd` function accessible from within your type (so you can use it in the various operations), you should keep it as a callable function. You essentially have two choices: You can leave it as in your original form, with the `gcd` function being defined *outside* of the class, or you can move it inside the class as a static method. The former option would usually be preferred for such helper methods, so you wouldn’t actually need to change anything from your original code. But if you want to move it inside, you can do it like this:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom

    @staticmethod
    def gcd (m, n):
        while m % n != 0:
            oldm = m
            oldn = n
            m = oldn
            n = oldm % oldn
        return n

    # and the other methods …
```

You can then refer to the method as `self.gcd(m, n)` like you already did in your `__add__` implementation. Note that you want to remove the `gcd` method parameter there.

An alternative solution to this would be to cancel the fractions in the operator implementations, but actually when you create a new fraction. For example, this would simplify `Fraction(30, 100)` automatically to `Fraction(3, 10)`. You could do this by calculating the gcd in the constructor only (as before) and reducing the fraction parts there:

```
def __init__ (self, top, bottom):
    # run gcd first
    m, n = top, bottom
    while m%n != 0:
        oldm = m
        oldn = n
        m = oldn
        n = oldm%oldn

    # and now store the shortened values
    self.num = top // n
    self.den = bottom // n
```

This would simplify the operator methods to something like this:

```
def __add__ (self, other):
    return Fraction(self.num * other.den + self.den * other.num, self.den * other.den)
```

Comment: @keggy You’re welcome! But please remember to upvote helpful answers and to [accept the answer that solved your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) to mark this question as resolved. Not only for this question but for your older questions too; you didn’t accept a single answer. Please take a moment to clean those up, thanks! :)

Comment: hey would you know how to make the add function work then?    def __add__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                     self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = self.gcd(newnum, newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

Comment: @keggy Oh, now I understand what you wanted to do in the first place. See my updated answer for more details on that :)